# How to make calculations with javascript or jQuery, grabbing values from various different elements?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently attempting to build a quote calculator for my first website, I have been learning Javascript for a week, I have used jQuery to hide various elements when the website loads then show upon clicking relevent buttons. First Q, by doing this, am I creating any conflict between any new javascript code and the jQuery code?

I have built a pop-out interface that breaks down services offered, there are 5 categories. I have further developed one category to show, when clicked 'How many boxes do you need to store?' with a textbox beneath it and a submit button next to it. On clicking the submit button it shows a new question; 'How long would you like to store for?' and two more textboxes named 'weeks' and 'months' with another submit button.

What I'm hoping to achieve is to create a function that grabs values entered into the first box, divides the given number by 18 and round it UP to the next whole number, even if its 1.000001. Simultaneously, I need the value entered into 'months' to be multiplied by 4.33 and rounded UP aswell. Then add the result from months*4.33 to the value entered into weeks to give total duration, and the final calculation must be (totalduration*2.50)*resultofthefirstcalculation. The final result must then be displayed in a textbox of my choosing as a monetary value - £0.00

Many questions:

Do all the textboxes I'm using have to be within 'form' tags for javascript to find them properly?
If so, does it all have to be in one form or can I use more than one?
Can I mix Javascript and jQuery within the same 'script' tags? If so, should one go before the other?

Later on, once the quote calculator is functional, I plan to use PHP to send an email to the user with their quote details, and to myself with the same. Do I need to make considerations for this in my HTML/Javascript? Do all the details I want to send have to be in: one form/more than one form/doesn't matter, can be any element?

Here is the pop-out button in almost perfect working condition (minus the calculations lol), slight defect with the elements on the right but I have fixed this in the website code. At the top of the script tags, at the bottom of the code, I have included my best try at doing part of the calculation after some mind-mapping to make sense of what's required and in what order.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body { width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center; margin:0px; }
    div#bodycontainer { position:absolute; min-width:100%; height:100%; padding:0px; z-index:100; }
    div.centerdiv { position:relative; width:1100px; height:100%; margin:0 auto; border-left:solid 2px #ddd; border-right:solid 2px #ddd; background-image:url(images/transport_background_alt.png); overflow:visible; background-position:0px 0px; background-repeat:no-repeat; z-index:1 }
    div#getaquote { width:320px; height:55px; border:solid 1px #516c84; border-radius:15px; float:right; background:url(images/quotebkgd.png) no-repeat #fff; background-position:500px -50px; padding:none; }
    button#quote { width:300px; height:50px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22px; color:#516c84; background-color:#fff; border:none; }
    p#quotetitle { position:relative; top:20px; left:20px; width:500px; height:100px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:28px; color:#516c84; margin:0px; text-align:left; }
    div#callus { position:absolute; top:435px; width:340px; height:110px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; float:left;/*border:solid 1px #000;*/ }
    div#emailus { position:absolute; top:435px; left:340px; width:370px; height:110px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; float:left; }
    img.icon { float:left; }
    p#email { position:absolute; top:10px; left:120px; font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; color:#516c84; margin:0px; line-height:34px; }
    p#smallertxt { position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px; font-size:22px; color:#516c84; margin:0px; }
    p#call { position:absolute; top:10px; left:105px; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; color:#516c84; margin:0px; line-height:34px; }
    div#minbutton { width:52px; height:52px; position:absolute; top:15px; left:915px;/*border:solid 1px #000;*/ }
    div#minbutton a:hover img { background:#516c84; }
    div.quotebuttons { position:absolute; top:70px; left:15px; width:200px; height:auto; }
    button#servcat1 { position:relative; display:block; float:left; width:200px; height:60px; margin-top:7px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:22px; color:#516c84; background:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; }
    button#servcat1:hover { background:#516c84; color:#fff; }
    button#servcat1:click {
    background:#516c84;
    color:#fff;
    }
    button#servcat2 { position:relative; display:block; float:left; width:200px; height:60px; margin-top:7px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:22px; color:#516c84; background:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; }
    button#servcat2:hover { background:#516c84; color:#fff; }
    button#servcat3 { position:relative; display:block; float:left; width:200px; height:60px; margin-top:7px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:22px; color:#516c84; background:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; }
    button#servcat3:hover { background:#516c84; color:#fff; }
    button#servcat4 { position:relative; display:block; float:left; width:200px; height:60px; margin-top:7px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:22px; color:#516c84; background:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; }
    button#servcat4:hover { background:#516c84; color:#fff; }
    button#servcat5 { position:relative; display:block; float:left; width:200px; height:60px; margin-top:7px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:22px; color:#516c84; background:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; }
    button#servcat5:hover { background:#516c84; color:#fff; }
    div#transportopt { position:absolute; top:73px; left:230px; width:500px; height:330px; border:outset 3px #000; }
    div#storageopt { position:absolute; top:73px; left:230px; width:500px; height:330px;/*border:outset 3px #000;*/
    }
    div#freightopt { position:absolute; top:73px; left:230px; width:500px; height:330px; border:outset 3px #000; }
    div#relocationopt { position:absolute; top:73px; left:230px; width:500px; height:330px; border:outset 3px #000; }
    div#exhibitionopt { position:absolute; top:73px; left:230px; width:500px; height:330px; border:outset 3px #000; }
    div#quoteelements { position:absolute; left:750px; width:auto; height:auto; left:750px; }
    form#form { position:absolute; top:270px; width:205px; height:225px; /*border:solid 1px #000;*/ font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:20px; color:#fff; line-height:30px; }
    form#quoteform { background:none; }
    input.formdata { height:30px; width:200px; border-radius:5px; }
    input#submitbtn { position:relative; display:block; float:right; width:130px; height:50px; margin-top:7px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:22px; background:#516c84; color:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; }
    input#submitbtn:hover { color:#516c84; background:#fff; border-radius:5px; }
    div#quotecalc { position:absolute; top:63px; width:205px; height:210px; }
    div#total { width:200px; height:52px; margin-top:7px; background:#516c84; border-radius:5px; border:outset 1px #fff; padding:4px; }
    div#tax { width:200px; height:52px; margin-top:7px; background:#516c84; border-radius:5px; border:outset 1px #fff; padding:4px; }
    div#grandtotal { width:200px; height:52px; margin-top:7px; background:#516c84; border-radius:5px; border:outset 1px #fff; padding:4px; }
    p.calctitles { font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; text-align:left; margin-left:5px; margin-top:0px; text-decoration:underline; }
    #numberprice { max-width:150px; max-height:22px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-weight:500; font-size:20px; padding:0px; color:#fff; text-align:right; text-decoration:underline; margin-top:0px; border:none; background:#516c84; }
    #storagebutton1 { width:230px; height:70px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:22px; background:#516c84; color:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; margin-right:10px; }
    #storagebutton1:hover { background:#fff; color:#516c84; font-weight:bold; }
    #storagebutton2 { width:230px; height:70px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:22px; background:#516c84; color:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; }
    #storagebutton2:hover { background:#fff; color:#516c84; font-weight:bold; }
    #backbutton { width:70px; height:70px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:16px; background:#516c84; color:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; margin-right:10px; }
    #backbutton:hover { background:#fff; color:#516c84; font-weight:bold; }
    #backbutton2 { width:70px; height:70px; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:16px; background:#516c84; color:#fff; border:outset 3px #516c84; border-radius:5px; margin-right:10px; }
    #backbutton2:hover { background:#fff; color:#516c84; font-weight:bold; }
    .optdisplay { width:470px; height:8px; background:#516c84; margin:10px auto; border:outset 3px #116c84; border-radius:5px; }
    .boxtext { font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; margin-top:10px; }
    #numbofboxes { width:85px; height:55px; background:#fff; color:#516c84; text-align:center; border:outset 2px #516c84; border-radius:5px; font-size:34px; font-weight:bold; margin:0px; }
    #numbweeks { width:60px; height:40px; background:#fff; color:#516c84; text-align:center; border:outset 5px #516c84; border-radius:5px; font-size:34px; font-weight:bold; margin:0px; }
    #numbmonths { width:60px; height:40px; background:#fff; color:#516c84; text-align:center; border:outset 5px #516c84; border-radius:5px; font-size:34px; font-weight:bold; margin-top:0px; }
    .btw { font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; }
    #smtbxno { width:85px; height:55px; background:#516c84; color:#fff; text-align:center; border-top:solid #fff 2px; border-left:solid #eee 1px; border-right:outset 3px #516c84; border-bottom:outset 2px #516c84; border-radius:5px; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; }
    #tick2 { width:85px; height:55px; background:#516c84; color:#fff; text-align:center; border-top:solid #fff 2px; border-left:solid #eee 1px; border-right:outset 3px #516c84; border-bottom:outset 2px #516c84; border-radius:5px; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; font-family:"Bookman Old Style", Times New Roman, Times, serif; }
    </style>
    </head><body>
    <div id="bodycontainer">
    <div id="getaquote"> <a>
    <button id="quote"> <strong>Get A Quote Now</strong></br>
    </button>
    </a>
    <p id="quotetitle"> <strong>Choose The Services You Require:</strong> </p>
    <div id="callus"> <img class="icon" src="images/phoneicon.gif" />
    <p id="call"> 0208 208 4411 </br>
    07850 495 804 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="emailus"> <img class="icon" src="images/aticon.gif" />
    <p id="email"> EMAIL: INFO

    <p id="smallertxt"> <strong>BelmontTransport.com</strong> </p>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="minbutton"> <a><img class="minimize" src="images/minimizebutton.png" /></a> </div>
    <div class="quotebuttons"> <a>
    <button id="servcat1"> <strong>Transport</strong> </button>
    </a> <a>
    <button id="servcat2"> <strong>Storage</strong> </button>
    </a> <a>
    <button id="servcat3"> <strong>Freight</strong> </button>
    </a> <a>
    <button id="servcat4"> <strong>Relocation</strong> </button>
    </a> <a>
    <button id="servcat5"> <strong>Exhibition</strong> </button>
    </a> </div>
    <div id="transportopt">
    <div id="dedicatedtransport" onclick="addselected">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" onclick="options" value=250>
    Dedicated Transport
    </input>
    </div>
    <div id="commercialtransport"> Commercial Transport </div>
    </div>
    <div id="storageopt"> <a>
    <button id="backbutton"> Back </button>
    </a> <a>
    <button id="backbutton2"> Back </button>
    </a> <a>
    <button id="storagebutton1"> Palletised Storage </button>
    </a> <a>
    <button id="storagebutton2"> Boxed Storage </button>
    </a>
    <div class="optdisplay">
    <div id="noboxes">
    <p class="boxtext">How many boxes do you need to store?</p>
    <div id="boxinputs">
    <input type="text" id="numbofboxes" value="0" name="boxnumber"/>
    <button id="smtbxno"> <img src="images/tick.gif" alt="proceed"/> </button>
    </div>
    <p class="btw"> Standard box dimensions: 40cm x 40cm x 40cm </p>
    </div>
    <div id="storetimebox">
    <p class="boxtext"> How long do you need to store for? </p>
    <p class="btw"> Weeks
    <input type="text" id="numbweeks" value="0" name="weekno" />
    Months
    <input type="text" id="numbmonths" value="0" name="monthno"/>
    </p>
    <button id="tick2" onclick="workitout()"> <img src="images/tick.gif" alt="proceed"/> </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="freightopt"> This is where freight options are displayed </div>
    <div id="relocationopt"> This is where relocation options are displayed </div>
    <div id="exhibitionopt"> This is where exhibition options are displayed </div>
    <div id="quoteelements">
    <form id="form">
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <input class="formdata" type="text" name="name">
    <strong>Business:</strong>
    <input class="formdata" type="text" name="business">
    <strong>Email Address:</strong>
    <input class="formdata" type="text" name="email">
    <a>
    <input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Get Quote">
    </a>
    </form>
    <div id="quotecalc">
    <div id="total">
    <p class="calctitles"> Sub-Total </p>
    <p id="stresult"> WOULD LIKE SUB TOTAL HERE </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tax">
    <p class="calctitles"> VAT </p>
    </div>
    <div id="grandtotal">
    <p class="calctitles"> Grand Total </p>
    <p id="numberprice"> </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var totalprice=""
    var storagetime=""
    var boxno=""

    function workitout(){
    var a=parseInt(document.boxnumber.value);
    var b=parseInt(document.weekno.value);
    var c=parseInt(document.monthno.value);
    storagetime=(c*4.3);
    Math.round(storagetime)=totalprice;
    document.quotecalc.grandtotal.value=totalprice;
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#quotetitle").hide();
    $("#callus").hide();
    $("#emailus").hide();
    $(".quotebuttons").hide();
    $("#minbutton").hide();
    $("#transportopt").hide();
    $("#storageopt").hide();
    $("#freightopt").hide();
    $("#relocationopt").hide();
    $("#exhibitionopt").hide();
    $("#quoteelements").hide();
    $("#quotecalc").hide();
    $("#quoteform").hide();
    $(".optdisplay").hide();
    $("#backbutton").hide();
    $("#backbutton2").hide();
    $("#noboxes").hide();
    $("#storetimebox").hide();

    });

    $("#quote").click(function(){
    $("#getaquote").animate({height:"550px",position:"absolute",top:"125px"});
    $("#getaquote").animate({width:"980px",left:"-245px"})
    $("#quotetitle").show(1000);
    $("#getaquote").css({"border-style":"solid","border-width":"2px","border-color":"#516c84"});
    $("#quote").hide(500);
    $("#bodytext").fadeTo(2500,0.15);
    $("#callus").show(1000);
    $("#emailus").show(1000);
    $(".quotebuttons").show(2000);
    $("#minbutton").show(1500);
    $("#quotecalc").show();
    $("#quoteelements").show(1000);

    /*$("#bodytext").css({"background":"#516c84"});9e9ec6*/


    });

    $("#minbutton").click(function(){
    $("#getaquote").animate({width:"320px",left:"435px"});
    $("#getaquote").animate({height:"55px",position:"absolute",top:"65px"});
    $("#quotetitle").hide();
    $("#getaquote").css({"border-style":"none"});
    /*$("#getaquote").css({"border-style":"solid","border-width":"2px","border-color":"#516c84"});*/
    $("#quote").show(2000);
    $("#bodytext").fadeTo(2500,1);
    $("#callus").hide(1000);
    $("#emailus").hide(1000);
    $(".quotebuttons").hide();
    $("#minbutton").hide();
    $("#transportopt").hide();
    $("#storageopt").hide();
    $("#freightopt").hide();
    $("#relocationopt").hide();
    $("#exhibitionopt").hide();
    $("#quoteelements").hide();

    });

    $("#servcat1").click(function(){
    $("#transportopt").show();
    $("#storageopt").hide();
    $("#freightopt").hide();
    $("#relocationopt").hide();
    $("#exhibitionopt").hide();

    });

    $("#servcat2").click(function(){
    $("#transportopt").hide();
    $("#storageopt").show();
    $("#freightopt").hide();
    $("#relocationopt").hide();
    $("#exhibitionopt").hide();

    });

    $("#servcat3").click(function(){
    $("#transportopt").hide();
    $("#storageopt").hide();
    $("#freightopt").show();
    $("#relocationopt").hide();
    $("#exhibitionopt").hide();

    });

    $("#servcat4").click(function(){
    $("#transportopt").hide();
    $("#storageopt").hide();
    $("#freightopt").hide();
    $("#relocationopt").show();
    $("#exhibitionopt").hide();

    });

    $("#servcat5").click(function(){
    $("#transportopt").hide();
    $("#storageopt").hide();
    $("#freightopt").hide();
    $("#relocationopt").hide();
    $("#exhibitionopt").show();

    });

    $("#storagebutton1").click(function(){
    $("#backbutton").show();
    $(".optdisplay").show()
    $(".optdisplay").animate({height:"245px"});
    $("#storagebutton2").hide();
    $("#storagebutton1").animate({width:"390px"})(5000)

    });

    $("#storagebutton2").click(function(){
    $("#backbutton").show();
    $(".optdisplay").show()
    $(".optdisplay").animate({height:"245px"});
    $("#storagebutton1").hide();
    $("#noboxes").show(500);
    $("#storagebutton2").animate({width:"390px"})(5000)

    });

    $("#backbutton").click(function(){
    $("#storagebutton1").show();
    $("#storagebutton2").show();
    $(".optdisplay").hide();
    $("#backbutton").hide();
    $("#storagebutton2").animate({width:"230px"});
    $("#noboxes").hide();
    $("#storagebutton1").animate({width:"230px"})(5000);

    });

    $("#smtbxno").click(function(){
    $("#noboxes").hide(1000);
    $("#storetimebox").show(1500);
    $("#backbutton").hide();
    $("#backbutton2").show();
    });

    $("#backbutton2").click(function(){
    $("#noboxes").show(1000);
    $("#storetimebox").hide(500);
    $("#backbutton").show();
    $("#backbutton2").hide();
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you might not fully understand what jQuery and javascript are and how they are used.  Can you please provide an example of what you've tried so far?  This just kinda sounds like you want us to do your work for you.

Comment: I am a fast learner, I have been learning HTML and CSS for about a year, Javascript is a natural and necessary progression. I have developed about 70% of the website purely HTML/CSS, this is for a pop-out get-a-quote button because the business owner misses a lot of phone calls and this would solve the problem very well. I don't want you to do it for me, but I would greatly appreciate if you could help me understand and apply. I can provide code if you want but it will be a lot to give proper context- couldn't fit it all in one forum post on another site-thats the popup button code on its own.

Comment: I think you need to spend some more time reading up on web development.  Note that jQuery IS javascript, its just a helper library, so of course you can "mix" the two.

Comment: Thankyou that confirms what I was about 80% sure about through research, just needed confirmation about it.

Comment: Furthermore, I know I **can** do it, there is no doubt.

Answer (score 3):

First a little context.  jQuery is just a library of javascript helper functions and objects.  It's all written in javascript - it is not a different language.  It is just javascript.  There is no such thing as a conflict between jQuery and javascript.

Some answers to your questions:

> I am currently attempting to build a quote calculator for my first
>   website, I have been learning Javascript for a week, I have used
>   jQuery to hide various elements when the website loads then show upon
>   clicking relevent buttons. First Q, by doing this, am I creating any
>   conflict between any new javascript code and the jQuery code?

Sorry, but this question doesn't make much sense to me.  jQuery is just javascript so there is no conflict between using javascript and jQuery.

> Do all the textboxes I'm using have to be within 'form' tags for
>   javascript to find them properly?

No.  textboxes can be anywhere in your HTML.

> Can I mix Javascript and jQuery within the same 'script' tags?

jQuery is javascript.  They can be freely mixed.

> Later on, once the quote calculator is functional, I plan to use PHP
>   to send an email to the user with their quote details, and to myself
>   with the same. Do I need to make considerations for this in my
>   HTML/Javascript?

When you want to implement this feature, you will need to add the appropriate HTML/javascript to your page.  Before then, you don't need to do anything.

> Do all the details I want to send have to be in: one form/more than
>   one form/doesn't matter, can be any element?

That depends upon how you're sending the data to you server.  If it's a non-javascript form submission, then all data needs to be in the form.  If you're using javascript to send the data to the server either via a URL or an ajax call, then the data can be anywhere and you can use javascript to assemble it into the right form to be send to the server.

Comment: Beautifully answered thank you very much. The latter answers are what I needed most, see next answer if you would like to be of even greater assistance :D

Comment: Tried to post working example but because I'm new I cannot answer my own question for another 7 hours lol, I'll edit my original question instead

Comment: @DominicB-c - don't ask more questions in this question.  If you want to ask more questions, start a new question.  This one has enough questions in it already.

Comment: I just edited my original question to include the code that's troubling me, sorry if I wasn't meant to.

Comment: @DominicB-c - you just added a bunch of code to your question and you didn't ask any new questions.  If you have new questions, please put them and the relevant code in a new question.  It is not good etiquette here to keep adding more questions to an existing question.  You can add clarifying information (particularly when asked), but you should think carefully about what you want to ask when first posting and not add questions later.  This site is very different than a discussion forum.

Comment: Are you available to chat? The questions I have you could answer in seconds..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get user input data after some submit button or other control is clicked. While you have a lot of generic questions, I'll just jump the boat and post the practical solution that you'll confront sooner or later anyway.

jQuery uses a `val()` method to get data from an input field. You probably want to use this method as a callback in a `on.('click', function(){})` event bind which would grab that value.

Then you can process your calculations, create a new input field and repeat the process.

Comment: Please see my original question again, I have included a working example of the pop-out button.